# Azure Function command-line fails when testing locally with AuthorizationLevel set to "Function"

Tags: azure-functions

I have several functions defined in my project and I've always published them to Azure so I can test. I'd prefer to use the [local command-line utilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local) and point Postman at my 'localhost' path.

```
[FunctionName("NetworkNodes")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> NetworkNodes([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "{DomainName}/{ApiKey}/{NodeId}")]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Testing");
}
```

I can get the functions to respond however they always return an HTTP 500 error since they're all set to require a function key to execute.

Is it possible to use a dummy function key when testing locally or how would one go about meeting the requirement for the `AuthorizationLevel` without changing the code to execute locally?

Comment: Turns out using anything but anonymous isn't supported with func.exe: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/17842

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to implement this is to use Azure Function Proxies. You can abstract the function's authorization level (and token) even locally. Use func.exe to test locally by hitting the proxy definition as described in this video:

https://youtu.be/9J_vpXPbpkc